# Remove reads that have low quality base calls

Tags: linux, perl, awk, fastq

I have a sequence data file in fastq format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format where the first line is sequence ID, the second line is sequence [ACGT], 3rd line is '+' and 4th line is quality values.

```
@M01610:118:000000000-D49F3:1:1101:14523:2546 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GTACACCTTCATGAAGAACTCCATCACCTTCATCTCCAGGATGCGGTCCTGGGTGCTGTTCCTGGCGATCTCGATCAGCTCGATGTACTCGTGGGGCACGTACTTCAGCTTGTGCCGCAGCTCGGACTTCTTCTCCTCCAGCTCGCTCTTCACCAGCTGGGATCCCCGCAGGTGTATCTTGGTATGCTTGTTCAGGTTGGAGCGGTGGGCAAATTTCCTCCCACAAATGTCACAGGCAAAAGGCTTCTC
+
CCCCCFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGHHHGHHHGGGGGHHHGFGGHHHHHHHFHHGGGGHHHGGHGHHHHGGHHHHHHHGHGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHGHHHHHHHHGGGGGGHGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHFHHHGEHFGHHGGGGGGGHGHFHHHHHFFHHGGGGGGGGGGFFF?FGGGGFGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF?FFFFFFEFFEFFFFBFFFFFBFF
@M01610:118:000000000-D49F3:1:1101:9569:5713 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CAAGGAAGGCACGGGGGAGGGGCAAACAACAGATGGCTGGCAACTAGAAGGCACAGGCTAGCCAGGCGGGGAGGCGGCCCAAAGGGAGATCCGACTCGTCGGAGGCCGAAAGCGAAGACGCGGGAGAGGCCGCAGAACCGGCAGAAGGCCTCGGGAAGGGAGGTCCGCTGGATTGAGAGCCGAAGGGACGTAGCAGAAGGACGTCCCGCGCAGGATCCAGTTGGCAACACAGGCGAGCAGCCAAGG
+
CDCCDFFFDCFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGHHHHHHHGHGGGGGCGGFGGGGDHHHHGHGGHHHHGGGGFHGFGAGGGGGAAGFFDBF-DFFF>DF;DFAFDF=CA>CFBE>FFCFEFBFFF0FDDFAFFFFEDC.BFFFDBF.FFEBFFFEFAAC=FFE?>AEFEBFBFFFFFFDFFFFC>-9>=ABFFFFBFFFFFFFFFEFFFCFFA9BBEAFEF
```

I want to remove all the entries where any character in 4th line does not match either of the symbols `?@ABCDEFGHIJK`

The output of the above example will be

```
@M01610:118:000000000-D49F3:1:1101:14523:2546 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GTACACCTTCATGAAGAACTCCATCACCTTCATCTCCAGGATGCGGTCCTGGGTGCTGTTCCTGGCGATCTCGATCAGCTCGATGTACTCGTGGGGCACGTACTTCAGCTTGTGCCGCAGCTCGGACTTCTTCTCCTCCAGCTCGCTCTTCACCAGCTGGGATCCCCGCAGGTGTATCTTGGTATGCTTGTTCAGGTTGGAGCGGTGGGCAAATTTCCTCCCACAAATGTCACAGGCAAAAGGCTTCTC
+
CCCCCFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGHHHGHHHGGGGGHHHGFGGHHHHHHHFHHGGGGHHHGGHGHHHHGGHHHHHHHGHGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHGHHHHHHHHGGGGGGHGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHFHHHGEHFGHHGGGGGGGHGHFHHHHHFFHHGGGGGGGGGGFFF?FGGGGFGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF?FFFFFFEFFEFFFFBFFFFFBFF
```

Here, the 4th line of the seq ID `@M01610:118:000000000-D49F3:1:1101:9569:5713 1:N:0:CTTGTA` contains symbols other than `?@ABCDEFGHIJK` and is therefore removed.

The length of the 2nd and 4th line for a seq ID is the same but it is different for different seqID ranging from (200 to 250).

A unit is made of 4 lines (seq ID, sequence, + sing, quality for sequence). I want to remove all units where quality of sequence (4th line) for each character in the sequence (2nd line) matches anything other than either characters of the pattern ?@ABCDEFGHIJK. I have tried this code and still working on it

```
cat file.fq | awk 'NR%4==0' | xargs -n1 awk '{ for(i=0; ++i <= length($0);) printf "%s\n" }'
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: A unit is made of 4 lines (seq ID, sequence, + sing, quality for sequence). I want to remove all units where quality of sequence (4th line) for each character in the sequence (2nd line) matches anything other than either characters of the pattern ?@ABCDEFGHIJK.  I have tried this code and still working on it  { cat file.fq | awk 'NR%4==0' | xargs -n1 awk '{ for(i=0; ++i <= length($0);) printf "%s\n" }' }

Comment: Have you looked at the various [FASTA modules](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=fasta) that are available?

Comment: @Tanktalus I have tried several tools used for trimming fastq files which include trim galore and Sickle. These tools remove reads which have low quality but there are still some reads which have bases with low quality which I want to remove.

Comment: Careful, while it’s true that FASTQ files are *usually* formatted such that record spans exactly 4 lines, this is not its definition. There are valid FASTQ files where individual records span more than 4 lines, and this might need to be considered when parsing them. Anyway, tools like Trim Galore *can* handle this case with proper configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{unit=unit $0 ORS} NR%4==0{if (/^[?@ABCDEFGHIJK]+$/) printf "%s", unit; unit=""}' file
@M01610:118:000000000-D49F3:1:1101:14523:2546 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GTACACCTTCATGAAGAACTCCATCACCTTCATCTCCAGGATGCGGTCCTGGGTGCTGTTCCTGGCGATCTCGATCAGCTCGATGTACTCGTGGGGCACGTACTTCAGCTTGTGCCGCAGCTCGGACTTCTTCTCCTCCAGCTCGCTCTTCACCAGCTGGGATCCCCGCAGGTGTATCTTGGTATGCTTGTTCAGGTTGGAGCGGTGGGCAAATTTCCTCCCACAAATGTCACAGGCAAAAGGCTTCTC
+
CCCCCFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGHHHGHHHGGGGGHHHGFGGHHHHHHHFHHGGGGHHHGGHGHHHHGGHHHHHHHGHGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHGHHHHHHHHGGGGGGHGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHFHHHGEHFGHHGGGGGGGHGHFHHHHHFFHHGGGGGGGGGGFFF?FGGGGFGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF?FFFFFFEFFEFFFFBFFFFFBFF
```

Answer (score 3):

Collect lines for each unit in a buffer; at each new header line process the previous unit (check the last line in the buffer, print or not) and empty the buffer

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

sub process_unit {
    my ($rbuf) = @_;
    if (not $rbuf->[-1] =~ tr/?@ABCDEFGHIJK//dr ) { #/ no extra chars
        say for @$rbuf;
    }
}

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 filename\n";   #/    
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @buf;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^\@/ and @buf) {
        process_unit(\@buf);
        @buf = (); 
    }   

    push @buf, $_; 
}
process_unit(\@buf);  # the last unit
```

Explanation of the check of the last line in the buffer using `tr`
(documented [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)):

The `tr/..//dr` removes all listed characters from its target string, returning the modified string while keeping the original unchanged (due to the "non-destructive" `/r` modifier).  So if there is anything left after the removal of allowed characters we discard the unit (don't print it).

---

*A note on choice of `tr` and efficiency*

It is possible to use regex and its match operator with a negated character class,

```
if (not /[^?\@ABCDEFGHIJK]/) { ... }
```

instead of the transliteration operator `tr` (which *isn't* regex).

However, even in the very best case for the match operator I benchmark the `tr` approach to be `25%` faster.  In all other cases `tr` outperforms regex's match by a factor of 2-4, at least.

The match operator's "best case"  is when an unacceptable character is at the first position in the string, so that it matches right away and doesn't scan the rest of the string. This is rather unrealistic, to say the least. 
On the contrary, statistically many (most?) strings won't have any of those characters and the match operator will have its worst case, scanning the whole string. Note that in all of this the regex engine's startup is probably the most expensive part.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that makes use of (1) a modified input record saver and (2) the transliteration operator modified with the `tr///c` **c** compliment switch.

(I simulated the file at the top of the script)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file =<<'EOF';
@M01610:118:000000000-D49F3:1:1101:14523:2546 1:N:0:CTTGTA
GTACACCTTCATGAAGAACTCCATCACCTTCATCTCCAGGATGCGGTCCTGGGTGCTGTTCCTGGCGATCTCGATCAGCTCGATGTACTCGTGGGGCACGTACTTCAGCTTGTGCCGCAGCTCGGACTTCTTCTCCTCCAGCTCGCTCTTCACCAGCTGGGATCCCCGCAGGTGTATCTTGGTATGCTTGTTCAGGTTGGAGCGGTGGGCAAATTTCCTCCCACAAATGTCACAGGCAAAAGGCTTCTC
+
CCCCCFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGHHHGHHHGGGGGHHHGFGGHHHHHHHFHHGGGGHHHGGHGHHHHGGHHHHHHHGHGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHGHHHHHHHHGGGGGGHGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHFHHHGEHFGHHGGGGGGGHGHFHHHHHFFHHGGGGGGGGGGFFF?FGGGGFGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF?FFFFFFEFFEFFFFBFFFFFBFF
@M01610:118:000000000-D49F3:1:1101:9569:5713 1:N:0:CTTGTA
CAAGGAAGGCACGGGGGAGGGGCAAACAACAGATGGCTGGCAACTAGAAGGCACAGGCTAGCCAGGCGGGGAGGCGGCCCAAAGGGAGATCCGACTCGTCGGAGGCCGAAAGCGAAGACGCGGGAGAGGCCGCAGAACCGGCAGAAGGCCTCGGGAAGGGAGGTCCGCTGGATTGAGAGCCGAAGGGACGTAGCAGAAGGACGTCCCGCGCAGGATCCAGTTGGCAACACAGGCGAGCAGCCAAGG
+
CDCCDFFFDCFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGHHHHHHHGHGGGGGCGGFGGGGDHHHHGHGGHHHHGGGGFHGFGAGGGGGAAGFFDBF-DFFF>DF;DFAFDF=CA>CFBE>FFCFEFBFFF0FDDFAFFFFEDC.BFFFDBF.FFEBFFFEFAAC=FFE?>AEFEBFBFFFFFFDFFFFC>-9>=ABFFFFBFFFFFFFFFEFFFCFFA9BBEAFEF
EOF

{
    local $/ = '@';     # set input record separator in this scope to '@'
    open my $fh, '<', \$file;
    <$fh>;              # discard first read (will only contain '@')

    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my ($test) = /\+\n^(.+)$/m; # grab the fourth line

        # print record (with leading @ prepended back to beginning of record)
        #  unless there  are unwanted characters
        print "\@$_" unless $test =~ tr/?@ABCDEFGHIJK//c;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, might check out:

```
 perl -ne 'if (/@M0\w*:\d\d\d:/) {$s=$_;$s.=<> for 1..2;$r=<>; if ($r =~ /[^\s?A-K]/) {next} else {$s.=$r;print $s}}' d
```